# How to set value that will prefilled on form i want to do for id

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I want to create a edit form and sent the values prefilled on these for how can I achieve this with `nativscript` and `angular js`

```
     <StackLayout margin="10" verticalAlignment="center">
    <StackLayout class="form" padding="15" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
        <StackLayout class="input-field">
            <Label text="Company Name" class="label font-weight-bold m-b-5"></Label>
            <TextField class="input" [(ngModel)]="input.companyname"></TextField>
            <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout class="input-field">
        <Label text="Phone Number" class="label font-weight-bold m-b-5"></Label>
        <TextField class="input"  keyboardType="phone"
        [(ngModel)]="input.phonenumber"></TextField>
        <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

     <StackLayout class="input-field">
     <Label [text]="params.id" class="label font-weight-bold m-b-5"></Label>
     <TextField [text]="params.id" class="input" [(ngModel)]="input.id"></TextField>
     <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
     </StackLayout>
        <Button class="btn btn-primary w-full" text="Update" (tap)="register_update()"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Have you heard of Angular's reactive forms? And where does the form's data come from?

Comment: Since you are using ngModel, if you just update input object (`input.companyname`, `input.phonenumber` etc.,) with values, the TextField attached to should be pre-filled. Did you try that? If you did may I ask what seems to be the challenge in it?

Comment: @Manoj i need the keyword as in html we set value

Comment: @wentjun yes the value comes from context params

Comment: @Manoj the your solution did not worked.

Comment: If Im not wrong, I didn't give any solution here but just tried to justify it's done by Angular by default, binding your data to input. Unless you provide us a Playground example where the issue can be reproduced it's difficult to debug any further.

Comment: @Manoj I just need the value to be pre fill for edit form.

Comment: @Manoj https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3986502/7a46a52917b898bed9f4163f7acdc48a check error

Comment: The error is self explanatory, you should have model defined before you can use it.

Comment: @Manoj  check these i needed to do
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=bchHLk&_ga=2.54192746.318943183.1556020812-114592074.1556020812

Comment: You have just declared the variable, the value will be `undefined` initially. You are trying to access it's properties for which the variable should be an object. Try `model: any = {};`.

Comment: @Manoj still not working https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=bchHLk&_ga=2.54192746.318943183.1556020812-114592074.1556020812

Comment: I didn't notice any chance in the link you posted again. It seems to work fine for me - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=bchHLk&_ga=2.54192746.318943183.1556020812-114592074.1556020812&v=2 If you are not familiar with TS / Angular already, I would recommend you to brush up the basics which might help you greatly as you progress with your app.

Answer (score 0):

These the solution i found passed the params to model and get it on view.

```
<TextField [(ngModel)]='model.mytext.id'></TextField>
 this.params = this.params.context;
```

this.model.mytext = this.params;